# How to write a Grafana Query to search by a value inside an Array

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to filter/search `Grafana` logs using a specific value **Which is inside a nested array**, which only returns **empty** results.

This is how a particular log looks like (I am here only giving a one log out of many):

```
{"level":20,"levelName":"INFO","data":[{"method":"post","uri":"https://glp-performance-qa.pla.pearsondev.tech/plaperformance/products/glp/query"}]}
```

how can I filter all the logs with `method="post"` which is a valueu inside the `data`

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
kubernetes.container_name.keyword:"$service" AND kubernetes.namespace_name.keyword:"$namespace" AND data:"[{method:"post"}]"
```

**Output:** nothing, returns no logs.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try with method also in quotes .   data:"[{"method":"post"}]"